# How can I create a method for retrieving user email address that is available on the client and server?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I've got facebook, google and regular registration/login turned on on my website.  The problem I have is that the email address is stored in different fields depending on how the user first joined.

For regular users, it is in field `emails[0].address`.  For facebook and google authenticated users it is in field `services[0].email`.

At various places in the client (templates, events) and on the server (method), I just want to call one method that works out which field to use and returns the email address.  I also want to do something similar for the verification field.

I'm fairly new to meteor and the only ways I've found to do the above so far is to repeat the same logic in the client and on the server which doesn't sit well with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to transfer the email address to 'emails' if they log in with facebook, google or another services for the first time. This would also make it more future proof incase you add other services, since meteor will always use `emails.address` (including in other packages)

Server side code:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(user) {

    user.emails = user.emails || []; //If its null set it to an empty array

    if(user.services.facebook) {
        user.emails.push({address: user.services.facebook.email, verified: false});
    }else if(user.services.google) {
        user.emails.push({address: user.services.google.email, verified: false});
    }

    return user;

});
```

Then you can just check `Meteor.user().emails[0].address` every time.

Note: If not published due to the `autopublish` package you may have to publish the `emails` field for it to work on the client.

You may also have to run this the first time for users who have already logged in before:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.users({'emails':{$exists: false}}).fetch().forEach(function(user) {
        var email = (user.services.facebook || user.services.google).email;

        if(email) Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id},{$push:{emails:{address: email, verified: false}}});
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if facebook and google both use `email` in the `services` key, if they do the above should work fine. If they don't you can edit out the key that is used for google or facebook, in case one is `emailAddress` instead of `email` for example.

Comment: This will fail if the user changes the email address they use with the external provider as you will forever be using their old email address. You'll need to update the stored value regularly. The other dilemna you'll face is what happens when the user uses more than one service to login. This is more common than you might think as users might not remember if they used twitter, facebook, or google to log in to your service the first time.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Meteor does not update its record of email address in the `services` field in the case you're describing either. If Meteor updates it the bottom script can easily be used to update records. In the case of using multiple accounts the user will still have the same email on file. You're more than welcome to provide a solution to your dilemma as an answer

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'd considered that.  I'll eventually provide a account profile page that will show them the email address that was defaulted from Facebook or Google and let them change it (with a new verification email).  Regarding the multiple services and how to integrate them - yeah, I'm not sure what to do there - I've put it in the too hard basket for the moment.

Comment: Good call. There's a bottomless pit of complexity with multiple external auth providers and identities